# There is a standard for the error codes in the drush_set_error() function?

Tags: drush

I usually use the `drush_set_error()` function when I want to log a error in drush, sometimes I just do something like this:

```
drush_set_error('DRUSH_INVALID_ARGUMENT', '....');
```

sometimes

```
drush_set_error('MODULE_NAME_INVALID_ARGUMENT', '....');
```

But I'm wondering if there is a standard or something similar to correctly name the error codes.

The only doc that comes in the [function description](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/includes%21drush.inc/function/drush_set_error/8.0.x) is:

> \Drupal\Component\Render\MarkupInterface|string $error: A text string
>   identifying the type of error.

Comment: I guess "officially" there isn't. But I would follow the same good practice/convention as with D7's [watchdog()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7.x) and use the module name.